# Transform digits in a determinitic way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash, sequence

I have the following algorithm question:
Given an arbitrary digits sequence, say 5-10 digits, and a seed number, say 5, 16 or 56. The expected result is a set of digits sequences. The size of the set is the seed number. For example, the seed number is 5, which means we have a seed set of {1,2,3,4,5}, for each of the seeds, we can only generate a deterministic and unique digit sequence from the original sequence.

Is there any hash function or library implemented in JavaScript can achieve that? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an arbitrary digits sequence, say 5-10 digits, and a seed number, say 5, 16 or 56. The expected result is a set of digits sequences. The size of the set is the seed number. For example, the seed number is 5, which means we have a seed set of {1,2,3,4,5},

<sup><sup>Ideally you should *try* to do this and ask help with the results; asking "is there / what is the best / do you know of a tool to do this" is off topics on Stack Overflow, and asking for the code is even more so.</sup></sup>

If I understand correctly, if you have a seed-size of 3, then you have a seed-set that is {1,2,3}, and you want three digit sequences of length between 5 and 10.

One way would be to build the digit sequence like this:

```
2 1 5 . . . .
```

where 2 is the number of digits required to represent the seed (in your example, 1 or 2 will do), here 15 is the seed, then any hash (possibly salted) of 15, converted to base 10 and truncated to the required length. There are libraries in JS that do both MD5 and SHA1 hashes. MD5 is 128 bits, which gives about 128/3.32 = 38 digits (you could also use CRC32, which yields 9.6 digits, but counting the seed size and the seed itself, for a 10-digit sequence you only really need 8 digits, so 9.6 is plenty).

This means that all your sequences from 2-digits seed numbers will start with 2, but they *will* be unique and deterministic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Iserni. Your answer really gave me a hint to the solution. CRC32 is better than MD5 and SHA1 for me.